# how can I reset iteration in TFS 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I am using Team Foundation Server 2010 to manage a project I am currently working on.
and I am done with sprint one but the date initially set as sprint end date is 2 weeks in the future.

How do I end the current iteration ? and How do I configure TFS to end the current iteration. and show me data related to sprint 2 when I access the project dashboard ?

How do I make TFS to ignore previous data gathered from sprint one ?

How to disable or erase a sprint ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very good question. The current version of TFS has nothing built in to specify the current iteration. You need to modify the filters on the queries and the reports to indicate you want to see the data for iteration 2 now.

To modify the filter on the dashboards, you need to modify the excel workbooks in sharepoint that are used on the dashboard. See the [blog of Sunder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sunder/archive/2010/01/07/reporting-in-team-foundation-server-2010-part-3-sharepoint-dashboards-sharepoint-server-dashboard-customization.aspx) how to do that

Comment: I did succeed in modifying the filters on the queries. but I still have a hard time to modiffy what appears under the dashboard.

Comment: See the modified answer with a link to the blog of Sunder